# How to mark risky variable as safe?

Tags: customize, file-local-variables, directory-local-variables

I have some customization in my `.dir-locals.el`. Some of variables set there are unsafe and when I set them and visit some file in `dir` for the first time Emacs nicely asks me to save their name-value pairs for future use in the current session.
There is a bit different story when variable is also considered as risky, then Emacs do not offer the choice to safe them for the future use and asks for the permission **every time** I visit any file in `dir`.
I've [read](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Local-Variables.html) that it is actually desirable Emacs behavior but it's a bit impractical to me.
I want to set up some variables for my project, put `.dir-locals.el` on git and let others in my team use my customizatins.

Mentioned [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Local-Variables.html) claims:

> Emacs always queries before setting a risky variable, unless the user explicitly allows a value by customizing safe-local-variable-values directly.

What I've tried is:

```
((clojure-mode
  . ((eval . (add-to-list 'safe-local-variable-values
                          '(projectile-test-suffix-function (lambda (_) ""))))
     (projectile-test-suffix-function
      . (lambda (_) "")))))
```

And it has no effect - it still asks for permission every time I visiting a file in `dir`.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you could declare a setting to be safe from the same file that does the setting, it would defeat the whole point of having risky/safe variables/values...

Comment: What with the point of directory/project local customization? :)
Do you have some other idea on this?
I'm tying to achieve project local settings which could be part of project's code base on git.

Comment: The safety part has to be done non-locally.

Comment: I suggest you `M-x report-emacs-bug` asking to be prompted to save the value as being safe, just like we do for other variables.

Comment: @Stefan I wish this to be possible and have some good reasons for that but is it a bug if documentation declares current behavior as expected? Or, is it usual to report someone's wishes as bugs?

Comment: Whether the maintainers will consider it as a bug or not is up to them.  But you as a user can decide that *you* consider it as a bug, and the maintainers generally like to know that, even if in the end they decide to disagree.

Comment: This is such maddening and unsustainable behavior.  These poorly designed intra-filesystem security mechanisms need a clear and serviceable override.